# Flash (swf) disappearing when opening a Fancybox presentation twice

Tags: fancybox, flash

When I first open a Fancybox presentation that contains some images (gif/jpg/png) and one swf everything works great, scrolling trough the different elements. But when I close the presentation and open it again, the swf is gone.

Have anyone else experienced this problem, and found a solution, or is it a bug in Fancybox?

Thanks in advance!

I am using version Fancybox 2.1.0. This is the code that I am using. PHP on serverside to list the different thumb(cases-div)>hidden images only shown in Fancybox.

```
<div class="case">      
    <a href="cases/1/filer/1.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="1">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img src="cases/1/thumb.png" alt="Cava Interi&oslash;r" /><br />
        </div>
        Cava Interi&oslash;r <img src="cases/1/filer/2.gif" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="1" alt="case1" style="display: none;" />
        <img src="cases/1/filer/3.gif" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="1" alt="case1" style="display: none;" />
        <img src="cases/1/filer/4.gif" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="1" alt="case1" style="display: none;" />

        <!-- FLASH OBJECT - This will only show up the first time I -->
        <object data="cases/1/filer/5.swf" width="1300" height="471" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="1" alt="case1" style="display: none;"></object>
        <!-- /FLASH OBJECT -->
    </a>
</div>

<div class="case">
    <a href="cases/2/filer/1.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="2">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img src="cases/2/thumb.png" alt="Eiendomsnett" /><br />
        </div>
        Eiendomsnett <img src="cases/2/filer/3.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="2" alt="case2" style="display: none;" />
        <img src="cases/2/filer/4.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="2" alt="case2" style="display: none;" />
        <img src="cases/2/filer/5.jpg" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="2" alt="case2" style="display: none;" />
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            scrolling: 'no',
            openEffect: 'elastic',

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what version of fancybox? ... also, if you want to get help you should also provide the code you are using

Comment: I am using version Fancybox 2.1.0. Added the code that I am using. PHP on serverside to list the different thumb>images shown in Fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have misunderstood the concept of the plugin.

Why did you set classname "fancybox" for all elements (images, object)? It does not make any sense, because clicking on each of these elements would open self into fancyBox and it be removed after closing.

Comment: That's the way fancybox is loaded, as you can see within the script tag at the bottom. I might be wrong, have not been using fancybox before, but the code is from an example on their website. How else would you load it? When I remove the class="fancybox" it doesn't work at all...

Comment: I can get the plugin to work perfectly except for the swf objects. That's the only problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: First, "the code is from an example on their website" - this is not true. There is no example where image or object tag would have the same classname as link. Second, actual example would be something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/SWueG/ (SWF) or this - http://jsfiddle.net/SWueG/ (inline)